# Neural Network from scratch : matrix version with numpy (debugging)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

Recently I've been trying to create a Neural Network from scratch in Python. I've chosen the matrix way using numpy.

My Neural Network has 1 input layer, 1 hidden layer with 10 nodes and 1 output layer with 1 node. The activating function is the same for all the layer and is the ReLU function.
The cost function is based on the Mean Squared Error.

However, at the first iteration, the correction on the weight / bias matrix has very big numbers. Meaninng that first iteration correction bias / weight matrix get only negative umbers so that at next iterations, prediction for every samples in dataset is "0" because of the ReLU function.

So the implementation doesn't seems to work completely right. I guess that maybe I'm wrong with the derivative of the cost function.

```py
from os import sep
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from src.NeuralNetwork import NeuralNetwork

# read training dataset
# 11 categories => 11 inputs ; 1 output (wine quality)
red_wine_dataset = pd.read_csv('./dataset/winequality-red.csv', sep=";").to_numpy()

# get dimensions: n lines / m columns
n, m = red_wine_dataset.shape

# number of different wines in the dataset
# we split the dataset in two so we have n/2
NUMBER_OF_DATA = int(n/2)

# number of categories = number of inputs = m - 1 (because 1 column is the true output = y)
NUMBER_OF_NODES_INPUTS = m - 1

# number of nodes for hidden layers 
NUMBER_OF_NODES_HIDDEN_LAYER = 10

# number of nodes for output layer
NUMBER_OF_NODES_OUTPUT_LAYER = 1

# number of iterations for the algorithm
EPOCH = 1000

# learning rate (eta)
LEARNING_RATE = 0.05

# split dataset into two : a training dataset / a testing dataset
training_dataset = red_wine_dataset[0:NUMBER_OF_DATA]
training_inputs = training_dataset[:,0:m - 1] # wine classifying categories (acidity, sugar, ph,...)
training_output = training_dataset[:,m - 1] # wine quality
#print(training_output)

testing_dataset = red_wine_dataset[NUMBER_OF_DATA:n]
testing_inputs = testing_dataset[0:m - 1] # wine classifying categories (acidity, sugar, ph,...)
testing_output = testing_dataset[m - 1] # wine quality

# architecture of the neural network
# number of nodes by layer
layers = np.array([NUMBER_OF_NODES_INPUTS, NUMBER_OF_NODES_HIDDEN_LAYER, NUMBER_OF_NODES_OUTPUT_LAYER])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  NN = NeuralNetwork(dataset=training_dataset, layers=layers)
  NN.gradient_descent(X=training_inputs, Y=training_output, epoch=EPOCH, learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)
```

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from src.utils import ReLU, ReLU_derivative, mean_squared_error

class NeuralNetwork:
  def __init__(self, dataset, layers) -> None:
    """[summary]
    NOTATION:
    X = training input (A0)
    Y = training output (y_true) 
    Y_hat = predicted output (y_pred) = = activated output associated with the last layer (that is the output layer)
    Wi = weight matrix associated with i-th layer
    Bi = bias matrix associated with i-th layer
    Zi = (A_{i-1} \cdot Wi) + Bi = output matrix associated with i-th layer
    Ai = f(Zi) = activated output associated with i-th layer where f is the activation function (ex: ReLU)
    
    L = Loss function (ex: MSE)
    Args:
        architecture
    """
    
    # parameters of the neural network
    self.parameters = {}
    
    # partial derivatives to update the parameters (weight, bias) of the neural network
    self.derivatives = {}
    
    # number of the last layer (the output layer)
    # number of layers - 1 because numerotation begins at 0.
    self.N = layers.size - 1
    
    # number of samples in the dataset
    self.m = dataset[:,0].size
    
    #print(dataset[0].size)
    
    # initialize neural network parameters
    for i in range(1, self.N + 1):
      self.parameters[f"W{str(i)}"] = np.random.uniform(size=(layers[i - 1], layers[i]))
      self.parameters[f"B{str(i)}"] = np.random.uniform(size=(self.m, layers[i]))
      
      self.parameters[f"Z{str(i)}"] = np.ones((self.m, layers[i]))
      self.parameters[f"A{str(i)}"] = np.ones((self.m, layers[i]))
    
    # initialize cost function value
    self.parameters["C"] = 1
    
  def forward_propagate(self, X):
    # initial the neural network with the input dataset
    self.parameters["A0"] = X
    
    # forward propagate each subsequent layers
    for i in range(1, self.N + 1):
      # Z^i = (A^{i-1} \cdot W^i) + B^i
      Zi = (self.parameters[f"A{str(i-1)}"] @ self.parameters[f"W{str(i)}"]) + self.parameters[f"B{str(i)}"]
      self.parameters[f"Z{str(i)}"] = Zi
      # A^i = f(Z^i)
      print(f"A{str(i-1)}", self.parameters[f"A{str(i-1)}"])
      print(f"W{str(i)}", self.parameters[f"W{str(i)}"])
      print(f"B{str(i)}", self.parameters[f"B{str(i)}"])
      self.parameters[f"A{str(i)}"] = ReLU(Zi)
      #print(ReLU(Zi))
      
    # for key, value in self.parameters.items():
    #   if type(value) is int:
    #     print(key, value)
    #   else:
    #     print(key, value.shape)
    
    # print("================================")
      
  def backward_propagate(self, X, Y):
    # compute derivatives of our loss function
    # we go backward
    
    # partial derivatives for the last layer
    dL_dAN = np.sum(self.parameters[f"A{str(self.N)}"] - Y)
    
    # Hadamar product: "*"
    dL_dZN = dL_dAN * ReLU_derivative(self.parameters[f"Z{str(self.N)}"])
    
    #print(dL_dZN.T.shape, self.parameters[f"A{str(self.N - 1)}"].shape)
    dL_dWN = dL_dZN.T @ self.parameters[f"A{str(self.N - 1)}"]
    
    dL_dBN = dL_dZN
    
    self.derivatives[f"dLdZ{str(self.N)}"] = dL_dZN
    self.derivatives[f"dLdW{str(self.N)}"] = dL_dWN.T
    self.derivatives[f"dLdB{str(self.N)}"] = dL_dBN

    # partial derivatives for the subsequent layers
    for i in range(self.N - 1, 0, -1):   
      # Hadamar product 
      # "*" is to multiply entries 1 by 1 => shape: (m, n) * (m, n) for any m, n 
      dL_dZi =  ((self.derivatives[f"dLdZ{str(i + 1)}"]) @ self.parameters[f"W{str(i + 1)}"].T) * ReLU_derivative(self.parameters[f"Z{str(i)}"])
      dL_dWi = self.parameters[f"A{str(i - 1)}"].T @ dL_dZi
      dL_dBi = dL_dZi
      
      self.derivatives[f"dLdZ{str(i)}"] = dL_dZi
      self.derivatives[f"dLdW{str(i)}"] = dL_dWi
      self.derivatives[f"dLdB{str(i)}"] = dL_dBi
  
  def update_weights_and_bias(self, learning_rate):
    for i in range(1, self.N + 1):
      self.parameters[f"W{str(i)}"] -= learning_rate * self.derivatives[f"dLdW{str(i)}"]
      self.parameters[f"B{str(i)}"] -= learning_rate * self.derivatives[f"dLdB{str(i)}"]
  
  def gradient_descent(self, X, Y, epoch, learning_rate):
    cost_history = []
    for i in range(epoch):
      if i == 2:
        return
      self.forward_propagate(X)
      self.backward_propagate(X, Y)
      self.update_weights_and_bias(learning_rate)
      
      cost = mean_squared_error(Y=Y, Y_hat=self.parameters[f"A{str(self.N)}"])
      cost_history.append(cost)
      #print(cost)
      
      # if (i % 10 == 0):
      #   print(f"iteration: {i}")
      #   predictions = np.argmax(self.parameters[f"A{str(self.N)}"], 0)
        
      #   print(predictions, Y)
      #   print(np.sum(predictions == Y) / Y.size)
    
    plt.plot(range(epoch), cost_history)
    plt.show()
```

```py
import numpy as np

# useful activation functions for hidden layer 1 / output layer

"""
@param x: np.array
"""
def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 - np.exp(x))

"""
@param x: np.array
"""
def ReLU(x):
  return np.maximum(0, x)
  
def ReLU_derivative(x):
  return x > 0

# loss function
"""
@param y_true: np.array
@param y_pred: np.array
J(y_true, y_pred) = 1/n \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_true - y_pred)^2
"""
def mean_squared_error(Y, Y_hat):
  #print("Y", Y)
  #print("Y_hat", np.sum(Y_hat), Y_hat.shape)
  #print("somme", sum((Y - Y_hat) ** 2))
  return (1 / 2) * np.sum((Y - Y_hat) ** 2)
```

Comment: Don't expect us to debug a lkt ofccode.  Your question needs focus.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. I'm gonna try reformulate and be more specific.